# Font-awesome icons not showing using Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, font-awesome

I'm new in Laravel framework and I'm having trouble on font-awesome. Icons are not showing or it's just showing rectangles. I install font-awesome using `npm`.  I already added below code on my `resources/sass/app.scss` as well.

```
$fa-font-path: "../fonts/" !default; 
@import"~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

Still I'm getting this error.

[image]

I don't know why that path is incorrect. Co'z my project is located in this path:

`http://localhost/Examples/Laravel/proj-3/`

**Addition:**

I found out that inside `public/css/app.css` @font-face{} src is incorrect as well. It should be `src: url(../fonts/vendor` and not `src: url(/fonts/vendor`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55568681/4479395

Answer (score 1):

Where are those folders? You can show an image of the folder directory, because laravel you have private folders and public folders, if you need call any font or css this need are in public folder and not in the private

Answer (score 0):

I Had same problem. 
Just copy fonts files in public/assets/fonts