# Laravel 5.7 + Font Awesome

Tags: laravel-5, npm, font-awesome, laravel-mix, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to include the Font Awesome toolkit in Laravel 5.7.

These are the steps I took:

1) Run `npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

2) Check the folders in `node_modules/` and everything looks OK.

```
$fa-font-path: "../webfonts";

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
```

3) Then I ran...

```
npm run development -- --watch
```

4) I see files in `public/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/`.

However, when I go to the browser the icons look like this:

[image: down_icon]

Comment: does your front end file load up the css in the public folder where fontawesome has been placed?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### **Laravel 5.7 through 7.x using Font Awesome 5 (The Right Way)**

Build your [webpack.mix.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/webpack.mix.js) configuration.

```js
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
mix.setPublicPath('public')

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Install the latest free version of [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) via a package manager like [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free --save-dev
```

This dependency entry should now be in your [package.json](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/package.json).

```json
// Font Awesome
"devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
```

In your main SCSS file, [/resources/sass/app.scss](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/sass/app.scss) import one or more styles.

```css
// Font Awesome
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

Compile your assets and produce a minified, production-ready build.

```
npm run production
```

Finally, reference your generated CSS file in your Blade template/layout.

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

Comment: Hello buddy! Thanks for answered. I done that, but : ERROR  Failed to compile with 15 errors13:30:59

These relative modules were not found:* ./@fortawesome//fa-brands-400.eot in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/app.scss ...etc.... and  .... ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './@fortawesome//fa-brands-400.eot' in \resources\sass' ...etc... Thanks!!

Comment: I could with the first option, but in a **new** project, I don't know why don't  in the other project....

Comment: Do you know how delete the Font Awesome's files and begin again ?

Comment: @Nico Yes, you can delete the @fortawesome/ folder in public/fonts/vendor. rm -rf /Users/Nico/Sites/laravel/public/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/

Comment: So do I keep the `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">` default link as well add the link you provided above? I see that one has `mix` and the other has `asset` in it.

Comment: @whisk Use one or the other.

Comment: If still does not work, add this to your mix file
`mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts', 'public/webfonts');`

Answer (score 11):

update your webpack.mix.js configuration as below:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
```

type 'npm run dev' in your terminal and hit enter

Comment: `mix.setResourceRoot('../');` made it for me