# Laravel 5.7 & Font Awesome

Tags: laravel, font-awesome, laravel-5.7

I followed this [particular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433486/laravel-5-7-font-awesome) answer to install Font Awesome in a Laravel 5.7 instance running on a LAMP application stack.

`npm run <option>` finishes without error. In the browser, Font Awesome icons don't load, but `php artisan serve` loads icons. I suppose I'm failing to include compiled `/css/app.css` and `/js/app.js.` What might I be missing?

**EDIT**

I didn't write any code. All I did is run a few commands from the terminal. My system

```
Debian Stretch (4.9), PHP 7.2.9, Apache 2.4.25
```

I installed Laravel with Composer. `app.js` and `app.css` files have exactly same page source when served using `php artisan serve` and navigating to `localhost/... /laravel/public`. So script and style files are loaded, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Can you show your page code?

Comment: I don't have a publicly accessible server. I didn't write any code. Not sure what I can show. I edited question; maybe someone can check this out in a similar system.

Comment: I updated the steps in the link you shared. Please try those steps and let me know if they worked for you.

Comment: are the fontawesome dependencies visible in `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation of FontAwesome.  Further examples can be found in my [personal web page project](https://github.com/commnerd/Personal), but the initialization takes place in resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js.  It looks like this:

```
import fontawesome from '@fortawesome/fontawesome';
import faFacebook from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faFacebook';
import faGithub from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faGithub';
import faLinkedin from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands/faLinkedin';
import faFileAlt from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faFileAlt';
import faDownload from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid/faDownload';


fontawesome.dom.i2svg();
fontawesome.library.add([
    faFacebook,
    faGithub,
    faLinkedin,
    faFileAlt,
    faDownload
]);
```

I then use it within my blade templates as follows:

```html
<i style="color: #3097D1" class="fab fa-facebook fa-8x"></i>
```