# Laravel Mix Fontawesome

Tags: laravel-5, font-awesome-5

I installed Fontawesome 5 using

`npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

Edited my app.scss by adding:

`@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';`

Using Laravel 5.7. The icons works when I access using php artisan serve (http://127.0.0.1:8000/) but when direct access through xampp (localhost/project/public), it shows as square. Do you have any idea? thank you.

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution? This happens with me also, I realize the webfa font files are mounted to localhost root path causing a 404 erro, but can't fix it

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I haven't found a fix. I just access the site using php artisan serve. Direct access to the laravel public folder won't work. Vhosts trick also works. In addition, php -S 127.0.0.1:8080 -t public works if you don't want php artisan serve. You can change the address to your IP. And it's great because other computers in the localhost can connect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.7 + Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433486/laravel-5-7-font-awesome)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to define your `public path` in `laravel mix`, because `xampp` use another root-path then `php artisan serve`.

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/index.php     //xampp
http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.php                 //serve
```

---

1 install `fontawesome`:

`npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`

2 Add to your `/resources/sass/app.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path:  "webfonts/" !default;
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands";
```

3 Add to your `header`:

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

**4 Add to your `webpack.mix.js` in your `root folder`:**

```
mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
```

5 Add some icons into your blade-files, f.E.

```
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
```

6. Run:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: How importing only a specific icon? This import method results in big source files.

Comment: Instead `@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';`, import an specific font. Take a look into your `node_modules/fortawesome` Folder.