# Why I'am getting wrong path in laravel to fontawesome?

Tags: laravel, webpack, font-awesome

Laravel 5.7
FontAwesome 5.7.1

I installed fontawesome via npm and imported in app.scss
Everything is fine, but problem is that I removed public/ from my url in order to access without this specific word / www.domain.com/public

So now my app trying to access fontawesome by this address https://test.local/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff2?3638e62
but this is wrong path because there should be public/ folder in address it must be so https://test.local/public/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff2?3638e62
If I manually add public word to address then I access to font awesome

My webpack file

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .options({ processCssUrls: false });
```

Any help

Comment: There *shouldn't* be a public folder in your URLs. That indicates you've set up your server in an insecure manner - `test.local` should be pointed directly at that `public` folder.

Comment: And how to do so? Should I have to write smth into .htaccess file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.7 + Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433486/laravel-5-7-font-awesome)

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

I put 
mix.setResourceRoot('/public/'); into webpack.mix.js
and run npm install so it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In your `resources/sass/app.scss` add this line:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all';
```

Then run `npm run dev` in the console. That way worked for me.