# Why Laravel Mix deletes CSS @import url()

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel Mix, and when I run `npm run dev`, everything is good, but when I run `npm run prod`, in minified style.css, all `@import url()`s get deleted!

**Webpack**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('public');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

I have no settings, and I use `mix.styles([sources, dist])` to manage my pure CSS style files. In one of my sources, I have something like the following.

```
@import url(../../dist/icons/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.css);
```

However, when I minify them, all @imports are gone! Is there any setting or something? Is `resolve-url-loader` a package to manage the kind of such things? If yes, would you please make an excellent example of using it?

Answer (score 0):

To import Font Awesome for compiling assets in Laravel do it this way...

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

See: [Laravel 5.7 + Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433486/laravel-5-7-font-awesome/52436453#52436453)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a font-awesome case, just change life easier by using a personal [font-awesome personal cdn kit](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/use-kit). All you need is to register an account, get a free or pro plan, and get the url.

@import url(your-fontawesome-personal-cdn-link);