# Laravel: Fortawesome/fontawesome 5 cannot display icons

Tags: webpack, sass, font-awesome-5, laravel-7

I have configured fontawesome 5 properly but still icons cannot be displayed. Am getting empty boxes in my pages. No errors while compiling. However i have tried working with fontawesome 4 is working fine but fontaweome 5 not working. How do i fix this issue?

app.css

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Variables
@import 'variables';

$fa-font-path: "/webfonts" !default;

// Bootstrap

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// @import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss";
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts')
   ;

mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../');
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me how you call the class in your html?

Comment: <i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>

Comment: Dig you link css file in your html file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.7 + Font Awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433486/laravel-5-7-font-awesome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this problem because of this line of code in your `app.scss` file:

```
$fa-font-path: "/webfonts" !default;
```

Comment it out and everything will work just fine.